# How to Setting Authorization Header in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to manually pass a token to the header so that I can authenticate my user. Because when I try to login the application says it is null.

[System.Web.Http.ApiController.Request.get return null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVxV9.png)

I tried using "HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader (" Content-Length ", contentLength)" but got an error in HttpContext saying that it does not contain a definition for "Current". That was the medium I found, is there another?

[HttpContext does not contain a definition for "Current"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D47Th.png)

[NonAction]

```
    public TokenUser GetUserFromToken()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> tokenList;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", contentLength);

        string token;
        if (Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Token", out tokenList))
            token = tokenList.FirstOrDefault();
        else
            token = "";

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            var msg = "Não foi possível identificar o token na requisição";
            throw ExceptionFactory.BadRequest(ServiceErrorCode.SingleUserError, msg);
        }
```

Comment: Please ask in English.

Comment: Or ask at https://pt.stackoverflow.com/